# Change SKlearn Linear Regression classifier to return more than one class label (nbest prediction)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, naivebayes

I'm working on a classification problem with [Sklearn Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) classifier in python. I'm looking for 5 predictions for each test data, but the default function of this classifier returns only the most probable class label.

I used Naive Bayes classifier from this library for the problem. It has `predict_proba` function that returns probability to each class. Is there any function can do something like this in Linear Regression?

Comment: `LinearRegression` is designed for the regression problem. If your task is indeed classification, you can use [`LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) with `multi_class` set to `"multinomial"`.

Comment: Thanks @SergeiLebedev.